# How to filter a mysql query with date range

Tags: mysql, date, coldfusion

I have a database table that accepts dates in this format: `5/15/2017`
Now, when I query the table with:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 1 = 1
```

There is form field which contains a date for filtering the query. The field value will always be in this format: e.g Today = `5/15/2017 - 5/15/2017`,
 lastmonth = `4/1/2017 - 4/31/2017`. The `form.date` consists of two dates separated by the `-` The month, day, and year.

Now I want to add a condition to the query. If the form is defined, filter it by date. So it will be like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="xx" name="ys">
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 1 = 1
    <cfif isdefined ("form.date") and form.date neq "">
    AND date = '#form.date#'
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

I know the statement inside the `cfif` is wrong, but how can I make the date search for the rows inside the database that span through the `form.date` value?

Comment: use < and > sign or between query

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If i use the < and > sign, i should be doing something like `WHERE date >= '5/15/2017 - 5/15/2017'` which won't work @AmitGaud

Comment: NEVER put a raw #variable# inside a SQL statement because that is how hackers do SQL injection attacks. You should always use cfqueryparam.

Comment: @Eccountable Thanks. I have always use that, but was just curious to get an answer to the question

Comment: Tip: Do yourself a favor and be sure to note that in any future query questions. Otherwise you are sure to receive the same (helpful) warning on every SQL question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Perform your logic before you submit the query.  Something like this:

```
queryStartDateString = trim(listFirst(form.date, '-')); 
queryEndDateString = trim(listLast(form.date, '-'));
queryStartDate = parseDateTime(queryStartDateString, 'm/d/yyyy');
queryEndDate = parseDateTime(queryEndDateString, 'm/d/yyyy');
queryEndDate = dateAdd('d', 1, queryEndDate);
```

Then in your query:

```
where to_date_column >= <cfqueryparam value = "#queryStartDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
and from_date_column < <cfqueryparam value = "#queryEndDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```

Comment: that logic will be in `<cfscript>`. Lemme try that now. Will get back you to. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is incomplete here is an example SQL-statement that would work if you separate the from and to dates, I would suggest you separate them both in the code and in the database, but most importantly in the database.

```
select * from table 
where from_date_column>='from_date' 
and to_date_column<='to_date' 
order by from_date
```

Comment: I separated them in the database, obviously. But not in the form. Is there a way i can split the dates in the form?

Comment: There probably is, not sure how how this form field works though, if nothing else I guess you could split it on the "-"-sign.